# PHP mongoDB SSH tunnel on remote database

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using mongoDB with PHP. on local system it works fine. Now I am trying to access mongoDB cluster on AWS which is secured by SSH. I am using below code

```
$conn = new MongoClient('mongodb://SSH Hostname', [
        'username' => 'username',
        'password' => '',
        'db'       => 'DBname'
        ]);

print_r($conn);
```

It gives below error

```
Type: MongoConnectionException

Message: Failed to connect to: SSH Hostname :27017: Connection refused
```

I can connect DB from MongoDB compass or Studio 3T. How I can use SSH while connecting using PHP

Comment: You need to create the tunnel system-wide outside php, e.g. https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example Then use localhost in MongoClient as a host name. Don't use it in production. It's for development purposes only.

Comment: error  Call to undefined function ssh2_connect(); I checked  php -i | grep ssh
SSH is installed

Comment: You need to create the tunnel system-wide **outside** php, e.g. ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example - a shell `ssh` command, not php one.

Comment: Does your mongoDB cluster live on an EC2 instance or is it on a standalone dynamoDB instance?

Comment: I used below command for SSH tunnel ssh -fN -i ~/.ssh/YourKeyFile.pem -L 6666:localhost:27017 userId@1.2.3.4

Comment: Still same issue.

Comment: Now I can access mongodb on server using SSH. Does but still same error when trying to connect from PHP